# Is there a better way than EventEmitter when getting a result from parent component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, eventemitter

I created a reusable component using Material table and I want to keep all the shared logic in my base component (reusable). However, when server side pagination, I need to call a list method from custom component and get its result in order to process in the base component. For this reason I tried to use `EventEmitter` but have not managed to return result. So, is there a better way e.g. using `BehaviourSubject` to call and get result from custom component to base component? Or any smarter way?

***base.component:***

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.matSort.sortChange.subscribe(() => pageIndex = 0);

  merge(this.matSort.sortChange, this.matPaginator.page)
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.emitToServer(pageIndex);
      }),
      map(data => {
        return data.items;
      })
    ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}


emitToServer(index) {
    this.getData.emit(index);
}
```

Comment: you can look into `Subjects` as a way to emit event details from one component to another. You can include it in a service file and subscribe to it as an observable. So this `Subject` can be reused in multiple components that listen to the variable changes.

Comment: @lanxion Thanks for reply. In that case I think it seems to be impossible to use EventEmitter easily. So, can I get just a single generic Subject in order to use for all the list classes? Or do I have to create a new one for each list? On the other hand, do you know any approach to regarding to server side sort, filter and pagination of material table?

Comment: What is the `pageIndex` that is emitted? And is there any specific reason for the `switchMap` here? They are used to map from one observable to another, not perform side effects like emitting here.

Comment: @MichaelD I use this approach for Material table pagination. Actually I was using a implementation before, but after converting it to server side, I had to make some modifications like that. pageIndex, etc is not important. Just concentrate on how to call the method from custom component to this reusable component and retrieve its result

Answer (score 1):

In your parent component you can inject a service that fetches your data.

Instead of:

```
 return this.emitToServer(pageIndex);
```

do

```
  return this.tableDataService.fetch(pageIndex);
```

In your parent component:

```
@Component({
  providers: [MyUserTableDataService]
})
class MyParentComponent {
  ...
}
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components

Comment: Thanks, but what about using a single generic method to get data for different entities? Or otherwise I have to move the custom methods to the custom components. ANy idea?

Comment: You can inject your parent component directly as your service. I think like this: @Component({ providers: [{provide: TableDataService, useExisting: MyParentComponent}]) class MyParentComponent { ... }

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem in another way, but voted up this answer for your helps also.